# constant unique ID generator

Tags: javascript, svelte

is there a way to create unique ID's for elements (e.g. by using the node of the element in an use:action statement) that will be constant whenever the element is rendered to the DOM ?
The reason why it has to be constant is because i want to use it for our Test Framwork (Selenium) and as of now our elements (mostly seperate components) have no ID's.

I am just curious if this is possible to automate for each element as it would save a lot of time of manual work and also reduces effort in the future as well as reducing error-proneness.

Has anyone implemented something like that before ?

Comment: Well, it depends on how your HTML is generated.  Is it from hand authored templates?  If so, just set element IDs explicitly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however i dont want to explicitly set the id - i want to automatically generate an id for said element that stays the same every time it gets rendered to the DOM

Comment: If you can identify a property on your element that's unique to that element (the tag name perhaps?), any hash function should do the trick. [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)'s `v5()` implements SHA-1, for example.

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of using test-ids, Selenium is capable of complex selectors to query for a specific elements in the DOM. Placing testid's manually and explicitly ensures that the tested element has a more reliable selector. It's a contract between the app and the testsuite.